# find the button onclick function in android activity

Tags: java, android, button

This is my login form is valid means :

```
 if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
    {
        if(DetailProductDescription.product_id==null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,WatchList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here i have to check another condition in else part:

in else part    having to check another condition:

if am getting the product_id on DetailProductDescription page without login :

DetailProductDescription class only having these 2 buttons.They are watchlist and wishlist.

if i have to click watchlist button on DetailProductDescription.class means its go to WatchList class.

if i have to click wishlist button on DetailProductDescription.class means its go to

new AddToWishListAsync().execute();    class.

How can i identify the these DetailProductDescription.watchlist and DetailProductDescription.wishlist button on LoginForm and how can i write the condition for these ??

please provide me solution for tehse.

Comment: Are those buttons in the same Activity, Login form?

Comment: @Nizam no..the buttons are available is DetailProductDescription class.if i have to click that buttons means its go to LoginForm.if successful log in go to that buttons class.

Comment: @user2218667 if you are already in login form then how you are updating `DetailProductDescription.product_id`? Also, if user had not done login then why you had come to the login page? I am not able to understand your page navigation flow. Can you give some more info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your Problem is,

> Button watchlist -> Login class -> WatchList class
>
> Button wishlist -> Login class-> AddToWishListAsync class
>
> 'Login' have to identify which button.

isn't it?

I'll suggest put an extra with intent call. ie,

in **DetailProductDescription**

```
watchListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailProductDescription.this, LoginForm.class);
intent.putExtra("from","watch");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

wishListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DetailProductDescription.this, LoginForm.class);
intent.putExtra("from","wish");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now, in **LoginForm**

```
String from=getIntent.getStringExtra("from");// you got it as 'watch' or 'wish', or null.
```

Now check the string and proceed.

Comment: yes i got it..thanks for your help..its successfully worked for my app...also i have learned from you...

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to have WatchList button and WishList button inside your login xml layout itself. The visibility of these buttons should be `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE` by default. Either you can hide these buttons from layout or you can do so in `onCreate` method of your Login Activity.

```
Button watchListBtn = null;
Button wishListBtn = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.your_login_screen);

    watchListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    watchListBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    watchListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this, WatchList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    wishListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wishlistBtn);
    wishListBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    wishListBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // your code to launch wishlist activity
        }
    });

    // your other onCreate stuff........
}
```

Then your login validation code

```
 if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated) {
        if(DetailProductDescription.product_id==null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginForm.this,WatchList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        watchListBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        wishListBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```